# Add suffix if doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**How to add suffix `/` if it does not exist using .htaccces / mod_rewrite?**

For example

Input:  `http://stackoverflow.com/chat`

Output: `http://stackoverflow.com/chat/`

---

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a redirect rule just before your last rule, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/                [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$  /index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

(Untested).

edit: oops, forgot to add the trailing / !

Comment: Result: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: was that after my edit or before? if before, yes, that's correct ;)

Comment: .... of course, the above will not work for any extra levels of "directories" in the URI. ( host/foo/bar/baz ). For that, change the regex to:  ^(.*[^/])$

Comment: Don't know about before, but I've test again and got same result, when trying to open `http://example.com`

Comment: I've just done a little testing, and it was working for me - bear in mind that your browser likes to cache redirect responses.

Comment: Just to clarify, this every solution is given at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html - in the section titled "Trailing Slash Problem".